# How to calculate Previous Week's last date for a given date?

Tags: c#, date

There were other posts for calculating previous week's last date, but all were considering current date...`DateTime.Now`

Here I want to calculate previous week's last date based on a certain given date.

Assuming Sunday as starting day for the week.

Is there any way to calculate Previous Week's Last Date i.e., For suppose a given date is `20-Nov-2015` is Friday.
Then Previous Week's Last day would be `14-Nov-2015`.

I suppose even if the date is `15-Nov-2015`, then its previous week's last date should be `14-Nov-2015`.

Simply saying how to calculate previous week's Saturday date based on a given Date ?

Comment: @musefan: Dude, I admit you were a great research person in c# and thanks for suggesting the qualities required for a programmer. I was just asking more info as currently I am viewing the answer in a phone wherein I can't workout or do some sort of research. Our world hasn't evolved to that extent where we can work from a Phone. Just you got the authority to down vote, I request you not to use it intentionally without knowing the actual facts.

Comment: @musefan: Please be patient and shows respect to fellow community members with your actions and words which encourages people. Your words are humiliating and discouraged me. I accept that there's another post, which I didn't found initially and neither been suggested before I post the question.

Comment: Erm... you can't fix problems with ignorance. If you want to take things personally then that's your flaw. I hate people that only ever be positive, makes others have a false sense of security. People should be told if they have done something wrong, or done something bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a simple loop :

```
string yourInput = "2015-11-20"; 

DateTime reference = DateTime.ParseExact(yourInput , "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime lastSaturday  = reference ;

do 
{
    lastSaturday = lastSaturday.AddDays(-1) ; 
}
while(lastSaturday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday); 


Console.WriteLine(lastSaturday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")) ;
// Should print 14-Nov-2015
```

Comment: I'm not considering the current data i.e. today's date !!! Based on a Selected Date, how to calculate the Previous Week's Last Date i.e. Saturday of Previous Week's

Comment: DateTime reference = new DateTime(2015,11,20); My input date would be in `2015-11-20` format. Will it returns the same as above as u r passing date in separated format.

Comment: @BhanuChandra: Dude, you really need to learn how to research stuff. Relying on people to do such basic things for you is going to get you nowhere as a programmer